# Show by example that the following statement regarding sequences is not true.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Apparently this statement is supposed to be false. If the sequence ${a_n}^2 $ converges to $l^2$, then the sequence ${a_n} $ must converge to $l$ or to $-l$.
However as far as I can see it seems true. Could anyone give an example to show it isn't?
Thank you in advance .

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ doesn't have to converge. Consider $a_n=(-1)^n$ with $a_n^2\to1^2$.

Comment: @PeterForeman. Thanks very much !